# AngularJS - fire ng-change on every drop down selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop down for selecting which report to generate, so when a user selects the report from the drop down it then generates it and downloads it for a mobile. Using ng-change it will only pick up when a user wants to generate different reports. I'd like it so they can select the same drop down item twice and have it download the report twice.

I have code similar to this:

Markup:

```
<div>
    <select ng-model="currentlySelected" 
            ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options" 
            ng-change="logResult()">
    </select>
    The value selected is {{ currentlySelected.value }}.
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {

    $scope.options = [
        { label: 'one', value: 1 },
        { label: 'two', value: 2 }
    ];
    $scope.currentlySelected = $scope.options[1];

    $scope.logResult = function() {
         console.log($scope.currentlySelected);   
    }
});
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/cf59ypyw/

What I expect is to select "two" twice and have it log the result to the console twice. Is this doable or should I be using a different directive for this?

Comment: @SoluableNonagon There is a JSFiddle available that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: It seems that this wouldn't work with ng-change as the value doesn't "change". The simplest solution is to have a button, like "Submit" or "Go" which will also make it available to download the generated report.

Comment: Why not bind a $watch to the selected variable

Comment: @SoluableNonagon I use to have a "generate report" button. It was requested that I remove it.

Comment: @ChristianStewart, I don't think $watch will fire if the value is the same.

Comment: @ChristianStewart could you demonstrate what you mean? I tend to avoid watches as they fire a lot.

Comment: @KyleMuir would it make sense to simply reset the value to the default ("Please Select") or something so they actually have to select that same report again?

Comment: @ExplosionPills that was my backup plan - was curious if there was a way to do it without resetting the model.

Comment: @KyleMuir you could use `ng-mouseup` instead/in addition to `ng-change` but this won't work if you select the dropdown and press Enter

Comment: @ExplosionPills ng-mouseup also fires when you select the dropdown, unfortunately.

Comment: @KyleMuir that's odd it does not for me, but I believe you.  You could still throttle this somehow though (with a timeout perhaps?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a button will surely help, it also takes away from any additional programming, it's just one extra element:

http://jsfiddle.net/ootnh0sz/1/

```
<select ng-model="currentlySelected" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options" ng-change="logResult()"></select>
<button ng-click="logResult()"> Go </button>
```

Update.

Resetting the form seems to be the only option left.

http://jsfiddle.net/ootnh0sz/3/

```
$scope.logResult = function() {
     console.log($scope.currentlySelected); 

    // once downloaded
    $scope.currentlySelected = null;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the client doesn't want a button which is how I initially had it working. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @KyleMuir it seems that you're only left with resetting the selection.

Comment: We ended up going with the reset option. Thanks!

Comment: @KyleMuir, unfortunately you didn't have much choice. The way select works is you have to change the value for change to fire. Otherwise, hitting ESC on your keyboard or clicking off of the select box would have the same effect as changing a value.